# Error NG0201: No provider for TemplateRef found when running cloned Angular project

Tags: angular, npm

I am encountering two errors when trying to run an Angular project that I have cloned from GitHub. First, I am unable to identify my project's root folder to open the source file in Visual Studio Code and sync changes. I would appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this issue.

Secondly, after running the **`npm install`** and **`ng serve -o`** commands, I receive an error message in the console that reads as follows:

core.mjs:8416 ERROR Error: NG0201: No provider for TemplateRef found. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0201

at throwProviderNotFoundError (core.mjs:225:11)

at lookupTokenUsingNodeInjector (core.mjs:3289:17)

at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:3256:23)

at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.mjs:10057:12)

at NodeInjectorFactory.NgIf_Factory [as factory] (common.mjs:66:102)

at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:3447:44)

at instantiateAllDirectives (core.mjs:11013:27)

at createDirectivesInstances (core.mjs:10486:5)

at ɵɵelementStart (core.mjs:13616:9)

at AppComponent_Template (app.component.html:2:39)

Based on this error message, it appears that I am experiencing an issue with the Angular error code NG0201, which suggests that there is no provider for TemplateRef. I have already followed the instructions provided in the Angular documentation at **https://angular.io/errors/NG0201**, but I have not been able to resolve the issue. Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem?

I expect that your project will run successfully

Comment: Since the name of the Provider is "Template-" i think you need to define this yourself (?) but thats not clear to us, since we dont know what repository you cloned. So fitting code would be appreciated. Or i suggest that you write an GitHub-Issue directly for the GitHub-Repo youre talking about

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got this error because I mistyped a `*ngIf` directive in the template (I forgot the asterisk)